# In crm module product with image is not saving in odoo9

Tags: crm, odoo-9

The error showing is record is deleted or removed when i try to save a new product with image.
When purchase module and inventory module is installed then it will save. When only CRM module is installed it is showing error.

[image: This is the screenshot]